# How does the "zero current detection circuit" work?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, power-factor-correction, diode-clamp

This question refers to the [L6562A](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6562a.pdf) PFC driver. My problem comes from the following highlighted text from [the AN2761 application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00195944-solution-for-designing-a-transition-mode-pfc-preregulator-with-the-l6562a-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

I can't understand the reason for 1.4V.

What's the meaning of "positive-going edge exceeding?" What is its relation with the  MOSFET's turnoff? What's the relation of all of these to arming the circuit? How does it do it? What's the circuit?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Crucial for your understanding of the circuit would be the knowledge that, in the upper drawing, triangle symbols with a glyph inside similar to ʃʃ, like that you emphasized with yellow marker, are Schmitt triggers. Get familiar with this circuit component, and you will understand the text of the AN2761 application note. The output of the Schmitt trigger is "armed", when the increasing input exceeds one predetermined voltage level, and "triggered", when the decreasing input falls below another predetermined voltage level (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AN2761 application note assumes the user is familiar with ST's power factor correction products. The document uses proprietary designations and abbreviations (like Vref2, UVLO, DIS), but has no glossary section.

Five interrogative phrases of your question cannot be consistently answered in isolation from the entire TM power factor corrector design solution. And this is disclosed in the application note, although a somewhat cryptic terminology may prevent you from using this document. I recommend you to read the documentation on L6562A predecessors which describes the TM PFC design in more details: [AN966 APPLICATION NOTE L6561, ENHANCED TRANSITION MODE POWER FACTOR CORRECTOR](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00004002-l6561-enhanced-transition-mode-power-factor-corrector-stmicroelectronics.pdf). You may be also need to consult the L6562/L6561/L6560 datasheets.

AN966 explains many designations and abbreviations (e.g., UVLO = undervoltage lockout, Vref=2.5V, Vref2=2.25V) and unfolds subcircuits of L6561 blocks, for example, Figure 5. Zero Current Detection, Triggering and Disable Block.

[image: ZCD]

The values of voltages and components differ for L6562A and L6561, but you can use Table 6. L6562A vs. L6562 of [L6562A datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/ba/de/2e/d0/3a/ca/4a/e6/CD00151385.pdf/files/CD00151385.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00151385.pdf) for intercomparison. The voltage reference at the Schmitt trigger plus input may also seem a proprietary designation, so I add an explanation

[image: schmitt]

Still, you need to learn the Schmitt trigger design and operations in order to understand the line `ZCD arm/trigger/clamp thresholds (typ.) 2.1/1.4/0.7 V 1.4/0.7/0 V` of Table 6.

The [PFC controllers](https://www.st.com/en/power-management/pfc-controllers.html) section of st.com can be useful for documentation search.

Answer (score 2):

Zero current detection is a technique to decrease the losses of the switching element and thus increasing the overall efficiency (Please Google *Critical Mode PFC* or *Critical Conduction Mode PFC*). In this technique, the MOSFET is turned on when the boost inductor's current dropped to almost zero so that the losses can be as low as possible.

The output voltage is higher than the peak of the input voltage because of the fact that the regulator works as a voltage booster. Now, look at the dots of the boost inductor's main and auxiliary windings. You'll observe that, at steady state, the dot-end voltage is higher than that at no-dot-end. And the auxiliary winding provides a ground-referenced reflection of the main winding's voltage.

**Since the voltage across the auxiliary winding is proportional to that of the main winding, you can have an idea about the inductor's current by looking at the voltage across the auxiliary winding** *(V<sub>L</sub> = L di/dt)*. And that's what the chip does. It measures the auxiliary winding's voltage and decides when to turn the MOSFET on again. It's also strongly recommended that you have knowledge about the Schmitt trigger as well just to understand the operation better.